# Duplicate search through two columns on separate tabs

Tags: microsoft-excel

*Sheet1* `Column G` has 1300 8 digit numbers.

*Sheet2* `Column D` has 23 8 digit numbers that match up to 23 numbers in *Sheet1*.

I need to locate these duplications on *Sheet1* and remove the rest of the entire spreadsheet.

I've tried following instructions, but can't seem to get it to work correctly.

If I learn the formula once, I'll be set! Thanks for the help.

Comment: There is no formula that will remove values from another cell.  This will need to be vba.

Comment: I can manually delete the excess data. I just need to find the matches between the two columns.

Comment: Then use MATCH() in an empty column to mark the ones that exist.

Comment: Thanks Scott. If I want to find the matches between sheet 1 column G and sheet 2 column D. I'm begging for a formula I can copy and paste.

Comment: "If I want to find the matches between" - what else do you want?? If you have the matches, you can filter for non matches and delete them.

Comment: If it's still not enough to solve it yourself, then please post some sample data so we can demonstrate on it how to do it.

Comment: Here's [how to use Match](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/match.php).  Put the formula on Sheet 1, with *value* pointing to the first of your numbers on Sheet 1, and the array as an absolute reference to your 23 numbers on Sheet 2 (e.g. Sheet2!$E$1:$E$23).  Use 0 as the match_type.  Fill the formula down on Sheet 1.  Matches will have a number, non-matches will have #N/A.

Comment: I got it sorted out with vlookup. I appreciate the help. It's tough when I can barely articulate what I need to do. That's a red flag on its own.

Answer (score 0):

You just perform the following steps.

1. In adjutant Column H of Sheet 1 write this Formula.
2. =COUNTIF(Sheet2!$D:$D, G1).
3. Drag it down till is required.

**You find 0 & 1. Where 0 for Duplicates in both Columns of Sheet1 & Sheet2, and 1 for Unique in Sheet2.**

4. Select Data Range and apply Filter for 1.
5. Finally Delete filtered Rows.

**Hope this simple method help you.**